# Using for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, automation, iterator

I have this line of code that i am using in order to create the table below.

```
DtTemp <- Dtable[,list("temperature"=paste(temperature,collapse=", ")),by=station.id]
```

table:

```
   station.id                  temperature
1:         S1     18, 20.5, 18, 18.6, 21.5
2:         S2 20.1, 18.3, 16.8, 17.5, 16.4
3:         S3   11, 19.1, 18.9, 17.8, 17.6
4:         S4     18, 15.5, 15, 14.9, 15.8
```

In the table above, `temperature` values are grouped according to `station.id`.

I am looking for to create other similar tables, **automatically**, for every other column in my `Dtable` dataset. That being said it is obvious that i have more than one `station.id` values in my original dataset `Dtable`.

Assuming that a `for` loop might do it, or something like `foreach` or `iter` how should i use them to implement it.?

Is there a way to achieve this, giving at each `temperature` column, as the example above, the relevant `Dtable` column name, for which the table is created.?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: And if i am not mistaken, `foreach` and `iterators` packages are not available in Rv3.0.3..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have access to the `.SD` variable which represents all columns other than the ones involved in grouping, so

```
Dtable[,lapply(.SD, paste, collapse=", "), by=station.id]
```

should do the trick

Comment: So is `lapply` doing the fancy work? I didn't know about the `.SD` variable. I was trying for `header`.

Comment: Correct.  .SD is hidden away in the advanced bit of `?data.table`  - there are a few other useful variables such as .I which can be of use, and a further argument to data.table of .SDcols which may be useful if you don't want lapply to hit every column of Dtable